# React Head Method 404

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React app using `react-router` and I need to have a route that can respond to a HEAD request for a load balancer in AWS.  I've created a route `/healthcheck` like so `<Route path="/healthcheck" component={HealthCheck}/>`.  The component looks like the following

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class HealthCheck extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Healthy</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default HealthCheck;
```

This returns a 200 for a GET but a 404 for HEAD.  How can I make it return a 200 for a HEAD request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't how you should do this. React is a client side library that only handles the view. You should be using your server-side logic to handle this.